# AnimatedVectorDrawable support < 24

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

I have an animated vector drawable asset in my drawables folder. I use the following code to run it on button click

```kotlin
val myVectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
            resources,
            R.drawable.animation,
            theme
        )


        button.setOnClickListener {
            image.setImageDrawable(null)
            image.setImageDrawable(myVectorDrawable)

            val drawable = image.drawable

            if (drawable is AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) {
                drawable.start()
            } else if (drawable is AnimatedVectorDrawable)
                drawable.start()

        }
```

This runs perfectly if the device runs an android version > 24 and crashes otherwise. I need to support android devices with minimum SDK 21.

My questions are

1. How to make my code support devices with `21` up to `24`.
2. is there a better way to run `AnimatedVectorDrawable` animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you are using an animated vector, you can use [`AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/vectordrawable/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat#create(android.content.Context,%20kotlin.Int)) to create an `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` instance that is available on all API 14+ devices:

```
val drawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(
    this, // your Context
    R.drawable.animation)

button.setOnClickListener {
    image.setImageDrawable(null)
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable)

    drawable.start()
}
```

However, if you want a more generic approach, you must instead use [`AppCompatResources.getDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/content/res/AppCompatResources#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)) instead of `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()` as that properly takes into account the `VectorDrawableCompat`, `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`, and `AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat` classes in a way that is compatible with all API levels:

```
val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
    this, // your Context
    R.drawable.animation)

button.setOnClickListener {
    image.setImageDrawable(null)
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable)

    if (drawable is Animatable) {
        drawable.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your build to use the support library implementation?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution

> ```
> android {
>   defaultConfig {
>     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
>   }
> }
> ```

Without this, the build system will create fallback (non-vector) resources for lower SDK versions instead of using the support implementation.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is correct, I would just encourage you to check that this is set to ensure that other VectorDrawable(Compat) cases also work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It was already added, but for some reason, my code didn't work for < 24 but now it's working perfectly.